# Can't able to send email using platform events

Tags: platform-event

I am trying to send an email when a platform event is fired.
Below is the subscriber code.
This doesn't send email to the recipient.

Note: The SendEmailResult gives success.

```
trigger ContactEmailChangeTrigger on Contact_email_change__e (after insert) {

    list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailsToSendList= new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for(Contact_email_change__e  contactEmailChangeEventForVar : Trigger.new){
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] { contactEmailChangeEventForVar.OwnerEmail__c}; 
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Admin');
        mail.setSubject('Contact email changed');
        mail.setPlainTextBody(contactEmailChangeEventForVar.Message__c );
        //mail.setWhatId(contactEmailChangeEventForVar.ReplayId);
        emailsToSendList.add(mail);
        System.debug('--------'+contactEmailChangeEventForVar.OwnerEmail__c);
    }

    Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(emailsToSendList);

    for(Messaging.SendEmailResult x : r){
        if(x.isSuccess()){
            system.debug('--- '+x.getErrors());
        }        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you have the logic inverted for success and failure. Suggest you add this detailed logging to figure out the problem:

```
System.debug('--- results ' + r.size());
for (Messaging.SendEmailResult x : r) {
    if (!x.isSuccess()) {
        System.debug('--- failure');
        for (SendEmailError e : x.getErrors()) {
            System.debug('--- message ' + e.getMessage());
            System.debug('--- status ' + e.getStatusCode());
            System.debug('--- target ' + e.getTargetObjectId());
            System.debug('--- fields ' + String.join(e.getFields(), ', '));
        }
    } else {
        System.debug('--- success');
    }       
}
```

Comment: It's showing success in the debug logs.

Comment: @Monish Best you make that clear in your question.